# Performance Excel 2013 vs Excel 365 at Sep20

Tags: excel, vba, vsto

Does anyone have any ideas as to why Excel from VBA has become SO much slower since Excel 2013?  Is there something that can be done about it?

For example

```
application.ScreenUpdating=SS:  t=timer: for x=1 to 1000: cells(2,2)=x: next x: ? timer -t
```

SS=true: Excel 2013: 1.3 seconds; Excel 365: 39 seconds(!)

SS=false: Excel 2013: 0.35:  Excel 365: 36

```
t = timer: for x=1 to 1000000: z=cells(14,10): next x: ? timer - t
```

Excel 2013: 2.6;  Excel 365: 5.1;  Not so bad, just half as fast.

Basic VBA empty loop seems about the same on both, so I doubt the problem is in VBA itself, but rather in COM etc.  I would expect similar results with VSTO.Net.

The time I measure do seem to vary somewhat on each run that I trhy.

I am not sure when this actually happened, as Excel no longer has version numbers, but this was Sep 2020, Build 13127.

Maybe they are responding to complaints that their JavaScript runs much slower by slowing VBA down?

UPDATE:  Added ScreenUpdating.

Comment: No repro at all in Excel 365, build 13304.20000.

Comment: @BigBen try opening a large workbook.  Then running this on an empty workbook.  Just having the large workbook open seems to change times dramatically.  Xl2010 through 365.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the XL Version, but what other files are open!

Times vary from 0.02ms per assignment up to a wopping 69ms if a big workbook is opened.  Even though the book being updated is empty.

XL 365 seems to be about half as fast as XL 13, which is what would expect with computers now about twice as fast as 2013.